# Помогите найти ошибку при остановке потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня код который создает два потока, и если они не успевают отработать в определенный должен прерывать их. Но что-то идет не так, потоки вместо того что-бы прерваться продолжают работать.

Вот код:

```
public class CounterOfSpace {
    private int counterOfSpaces;
    private int counterOfWords;
    private String text;
    private Thread thread01;
    private Thread thread02;

    public CounterOfSpace(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    void startAll() {
        System.out.println("Start program");

        calcWords();
        calcSpaces();
        stopThreads();
        thread01.start();
        thread02.start();
        try {
            thread01.join();
            thread02.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finish program");
    }

    private void calcSpaces() {
        thread01 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (text.length() == 0) return;
                for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                    if (c == ' ') {
                        counterOfSpaces++;
                        System.out.println("counterOfSpaces "+counterOfSpaces);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void calcWords() {
        thread02 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (text.length() == 0) return;
                String[] words = text.split(" ");
                for (String word : words) {
                    if (!word.equals(" ")) {
                        counterOfWords++;
                        System.out.println("counterOfWords "+counterOfWords);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void stopThreads() {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
        Future handler1 = executor.submit(thread01);
        Future handler2 = executor.submit(thread02);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler1.cancel(true);
                handler2.cancel(true);
            }
        };
        executor.schedule(r, 3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

В самом низу, метод который в последней строчке должен останавливать потоки `executor.schedule(r, 3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`. Среднее время выполнения этой программы, без прерываний, около 40 мс, так что 3 мс вполне достаточно.
Но программа и с вызывом метода `stopThreads()` так же отрабатывает до конца все потоки, и 3мс совершенно ее не смущают. Помогите разобраться что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Вы запускаете потоки 2 раза: через `Thread.start()` и через `ScheduledExecutorService.submit()`
- Полагаться на время при работе с потоками - плохая идея.
- Поток может быть остановлен при помощи метода `Thread.stop()` - но этот метод ненадежный и устаревший, подробнее можно почитать здесь: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html
- Как написал Eugene Krivenja, для корректного завершения потока нужно руками проверять условие остановки - либо с помощью дополнительной переменной, либо с помощью метода `Thread.interrupted()`

Пример с ExecutorService и interrupted():

```
public class CounterOfSpace {
    private int counterOfSpaces;
    private int counterOfWords;
    private String text;
    private ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
    private Future<?> handler1, handler2;

    public CounterOfSpace(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    void startAll() {
        System.out.println("Start program");
        handler1 = executor.submit(this::calcWords);
        handler2 = executor.submit(this::calcSpaces);
        executor.schedule(this::stopThreads, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        try {
            // Завершает работу executor-a и ожидает завершения
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finish program");
    }

    private void calcSpaces() {
        if (!text.isEmpty())
            for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                // Проверяем статус interrupted
                if (Thread.interrupted())
                    return;
                if (c == ' ') {
                    counterOfSpaces++;
                    System.out.println("counterOfSpaces " + counterOfSpaces);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // После выброса исключения InterruptedException
                    // статус interrupted очищается и его надо
                    // установить снова
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
    }

    private void calcWords() {
        if (!text.isEmpty())
            for (String word : text.split(" +")) {
                if (Thread.interrupted())
                    return;
                counterOfWords++;
                System.out.println("counterOfWords " + counterOfWords);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
    }

    private void stopThreads() {
        // FutureTask.cancel(true) вызывает метод Thread.interrupt()
        handler1.cancel(true);
        handler2.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @zRrr, ошибся, признаю.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял ваш код, вы неверно понимаете что такое `Thread` и что такое  `Executor`. Вторые появились гораздо позже первых, и их по сути мало что связывает.

Поэтому, если вы запускаете `Thread.start()`, то уже ничего вам не поможет его остановить.

**ПРИМЕР**: как останавливать поток

```
// set this to true to stop the thread
volatile boolean shutdown = false;
...
public void run() {
  while (!shutdown) {
      // continue processing
  }
}
```

Comment: >>>если вы запускаете Thread.start(), то уже ничего вам не поможет его остановить<<< не может быть как-то же можно остановить поток.

Comment: В методе `run()` проверяйте при каждой итерации цикла какую-нибудь переменную, объявленную вне потока, и по условию выходите из метода. Это все что могу подсказать.

Comment: По этой причине `Thread` считается морально устаревшим и вместо него лучше пользоваться `Executor`-ом.

Comment: Дополнил ответ примером, если вы решите остаться с `Thread`. Раз вы останавливаете оба потока одновременно, переменная может быть в вашем случае одна.

Comment: Thread не считается морально устаревшим. Это просто более низкоуровневое апи.

Comment: "потому что оба Future не были даже запущены" - эмм, что? Future вообще не может быть запущен  - он нужен для получения результата выполнения таска. А метод submit() как раз эти таски и запускает.

Comment: `Executor.execute()` запускает сразу же, либо ставит в очередь на исполнение если все треды заняты.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja то есть если я не вызвал `.get()`, то таск никогда не исполнится? Серьезно?

Comment: @etki, вы правы, исполнится. Ошибся.